# How can I interleave 5 PyTorch tensors?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have 5 tensors of shape `torch.Size([7, 20, 180])`

I want to interleave them, one after the other along `dim=1`. So that my final shape will be `torch.Size([7, 100, 180])`.

Basically, I want the first element from the first tensor, then the first element from the second tensor, and so on.

Comment: You want either `torch.expand` or `torch.repeat`, though more information is needed. See here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-repeat-and-torch-expand-which-to-use/27969

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correctly,

```py
import torch
stacked = torch.stack(list_of_tensors, dim=2)
interleaved = torch.flatten(stacked, start_dim=1, end_dim=2)
```

`interleaved` is what you need apparently

(tested with pytorch 1.1.0)